# How to filter pivot table using inputbox in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, pivot-table

I would like to filter pivot table using inputbox. I need to make visible ony the user entered values and other values must be invisible. The pivot field "Number" is in Row Labels. I used loop in the code. so user the can enter multiple values. I used the code below but the problem is it is not working and showing Error "Subscript out of range". Help me

```
Sub FilterRP()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim str1 As Variant
Dim arr1() As String
Dim i As Long

Set ws = Sheets("Main")

i = 1
Do
    str1 = Application.InputBox("Select one Number")
    ReDim Preserve arr1(i)
    arr1(i) = str1
    i = i + 1
Loop While (str1 <> vbNullString) And (str1 <> False)

ws.PivotTables("MainTable").PivotFields("Number").ClearAllFilters

ws.PivotTables("MainTable").PivotFields("Number").PivotItems(arr1(i)).Visible = True

End Sub
```

Comment: ReDim preserve is inefficient as you end up creating new arrays and coping info. Is it possible to read a "," separated string in from the Inputbox and use Split on that to create your array? I'm sure someone will correct me if that is less efficient.  Then loop the array setting the pivottable visible items = to the array items.

Comment: On whcih line do you get the error?

Comment: @ashleedawg On the last line on `PivotItems(arr1(i)).Visible `

Comment: @Deepak can you explain what is "stops working" ? is it stuck ? are yu getting an error ? run the code in Debug mode (with `{F8}`) and let us know at what line you are getting an error

Comment: showing Error "Subscript out of range" in ` PivotItems(arr1(i)).Visible`

Comment: @Deepak read my answer and code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below, explanations inside the code's comments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterRP()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim str1 As Variant
Dim arr1() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim PvtItm As PivotItem

Set ws = Sheets("Main")

i = 0
Do
    str1 = Application.InputBox("Select one Number")
    ReDim Preserve arr1(i)
    arr1(i) = str1
    i = i + 1
Loop While (str1 <> vbNullString) And (str1 <> False)

With ws.PivotTables("MainTable").PivotFields("Number")
    .ClearAllFilters ' reset previous filters

    ' loop through Pivot Items collection
    For Each PvtItm In .PivotItems
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(PvtItm.Name, arr1, 0)) Then ' check if current Pivot-Items's name equals to one of the selected values in Input-Box
            PvtItm.Visible = True
        Else
            PvtItm.Visible = False
        End If
    Next PvtItm
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try doing something like this. It takes an input from your `InputBox` separated by commas. Then loops through each item in the Pivot Field 'Number' setting the visibility if the value exists in the array. If the array `IsEmpty` (i.e. the input box was `vbNullString`) then it resets the Pivot Field and returns all items.

```
Sub FilterRP()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim str1 As Variant
    Dim arr1() As String
    Dim pi As PivotItem

    Set ws = Sheets("Main")

    str1 = InputBox("Please enter the numbers you want to filter by" & vbNewLine & "Seperated by a comma (,)")
    ' Remove spaces if any
    str1 = Trim(Replace(str1, " ", vbNullString))

    arr1 = Split(str1, ",")
    With ws.PivotTables("MainTable").PivotFields("Number")
        For Each pi In .PivotItems
            If Not str1 = vbNullString Then
                pi.Visible = IIf(IsInArray(pi.Name, arr1), True, False)
            Else
                pi.Visible = True
            End If
        Next pi
    End With
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim i
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i) = stringToBeFound Then
            IsInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    IsInArray = False
End Function
```

Comment: I already tried using Split function. But when i run the code my excel stops responding. But anyhow thanks for the code

Comment: When you run what code? How many items are in your pivot table?

Comment: When i run your code. I have 73 items in that pivot field